# Magento 2 - Admin form datepicker not working in custom tab

Tags: magento2, customer-account, adminform, tabs, datepicker

I have a custom tab in admin customer account edit. I have two date fields but the datepicker is not working. Below is my code.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;

class Tabs extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_dob = null;

    /**
     * Core registry.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;
    /**
     * @var Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_country;


    /**
     * Tabs constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $country
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $country,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_country = $country;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry(
            RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Other Account Information');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Other Account Information');
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Tab class getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Return URL link to Tab content.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Tab should be loaded trough Ajax call.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function initForm()
    {
        if (!$this->canShowTab()) {
            return $this;
        }
        /**@var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('custominfo_');
        $customerId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry(
            RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID
        );
        $storeid = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Other Profile Information')]
        );
        $customer = $this->_objectManager->create(
            'Magento\Customer\Model\Customer'
        )->load($customerId);

        $contract = $this->_objectManager->create(
            'Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit'
        )->getContractInfoCollection();

        if (isset($contract['start_date'])) {
            $contract_start_date = $contract['start_date'];
        } else {
            $contract_start_date = "";
        }
        $fieldset->addField(
            'start_date',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'start_date',
                'class' => '_has-datepicker',
                'label' => __('Contract Start Date'),
                'title' => __('Contract Start Date'),
                'format' => $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT)
            ]
        );
        if (isset($contract['end_date'])) {
            $contract_end_date = $contract['end_date'];
        } else {
            $contract_end_date = "";
        }
        $fieldset->addField(
            'end_date',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'end_date',
                'class' => '_has-datepicker',
                'label' => __('Contract End Date'),
                'title' => __('Contract End Date'),
                'date_format' => $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT),
                'time_format' => $this->_localeDate->getTimeFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT)
            ]
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);

        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if ($this->canShowTab()) {
            $this->initForm();

            return parent::_toHtml();
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the layout.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function getFormHtml()
    {
        $html = parent::getFormHtml();
        $html .= $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Js'
        )->toHtml();

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Below is how it looks in the admin. It just appearing like a text box only.
[image]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it is working for me.

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'start_date',
        'date',
        [
            'name' => 'start_date',
            'label' => __('Date'),
            'title' => __('Date'),
            'required' => true,
            'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'time_format' => 'hh:mm:ss'
        ]
);
```

Comment: Still I have to call a js and call the $('#start_date').calendar({}); Your answer helped me. Thank you.